# Node Express Get request passing a custom header

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I am trying to make a get request equivalent to this jQuery:

```
  $.ajax({
    headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': 'YOUR_API_KEY' },
    url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/BL1/standings',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
  }).done(function(response) {       
    console.log(response);
  });
```

However, I haven't figured out how to do it using nodejs - express. This code is from an api routes module attached to the main app.
The request seems to work, collecting the data but does not end. Also, I cannot see the custom header in the request when inspecting from the browser.

```
   app.get('/api/:league', function(req, res, next) {

      var apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;    
      let url = 'api.football-data.org';

      var options = {
        host: url,
        method: 'GET',
        path: 'v2/competitions/BL1/standings',
        headers: {
          'X-Auth-Token': apiKey
        }
      };

      let data = "";
      var getReq = http.request(options,function(resp){

         console.log("Connected");        
         resp.on("data", chunk => {
          data += chunk;
         });

         resp.on("end", () => {
           console.log("data collected");
         });
      });

      getReq.on("error", (err) => console.log("OOPS!", err));

      getReq.end(JSON.stringify(data));

  })
```

[Link to project](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/football-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using request-promise npm package.https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

```
var rp = require(request-promise);

const baseUrl = 'api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/BL1/standings';
const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;

var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: baseUrl,
  headers: {
      'X-Auth-Token': apiKey
  },
  json: true
};

rp(options)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response)
  }
);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery ajax function does not have `headers` option. You can read about this function on official doc http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ . They custom request header by `beforeSend` function way:

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token", 'YOUR_API_KEY');
    },
    url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/BL1/standings',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
}).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

With `http node lib`, you can flow this example

```
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    // TODO: send data to client
    // res.status(200).json(JSON.stringify(body.toString()))
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.end();
```

Comment: The 16th parameter listed is *headers*: An object of additional header key/value pairs to send along with requests using the XMLHttpRequest transport. It does work, I tested it.

Comment: Ok I tried your code and it works saving the data :) but outputting the JSON to the client didn't format properly.

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle My mistake, just use `JSON.parse` instead of `JSON.stringify`